# Замедление секундомера

Tags: java

Я новичок в JAVA. Просмотрев несколько примеров - написал подобие секундомера используя Timer. После выполнения программы, 500 минут секундомера пролетают за 2 - 3 секунды. Видимо где-то что-то напутал с синтаксисом. Буду признателен за помощь. Также приму любые предложения по оптимизации данного кода.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ut extends TimerTask {
Timer timer;
    public void run(){
        int seconds = 0, minutes = 0;
        while (true) {
        seconds++;
        if (minutes != 0)
          System.out.print(minutes + ":");
          System.out.println(seconds);
        if (seconds == 59) {
          seconds = -1;
          minutes++;
        }
        if (minutes == 500){
            timer.cancel();
        }
      }
  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Timer().schedule(new ut(), 10);
    } 
}
```

Читал также, что можно как то реализовать данную задачу через swing. Если кто нибудь знает как это реализовать и будет ли это проще чем данный пример, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Вопрос решен. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Comment: какую, тебе же сказали, что время должно быть в милисекундах, это (1сек х 1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
...
// Будет вызываться каждую секунду
timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        System.out.println("WOW!");
    }
));
timer.start();
```

[Источник](http://forum.vingrad.ru/faq/topic-157924.html).

Answer (score 1):

В Java времена в миллисекундах.